# Mysql WHERE field1 or field2 in (Subquery)

Tags: sql, mysql, select, subquery

Table `offers` has the offers with their details.

Table `combinedofferstbl` has two columns: `offer_id` and `combinedwithoffer_id`.

Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM combined offers 
WHERE combinedofferstbl.offer_id
OR combinedofferstbl.combinedwithoffer_id IN (
    SELECT offer_id 
    FROM offers_tbl)
```

This way I can find a combined offer which has been combined either on the left or right.

I can't use OR in that way.

What is a way to do it without repetition of the `IN (...offerstbl...)` twice, one for each of the two columns in the combined table?

I want to do this because the real version of the IN subquery is quite long.

Comment: Could you share sample data and expected output in table format? [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "something like" is neither clear nor helpful. Code that doesn't do what you want does not communicate what you wished it did. The rest isn't clear either. Please: Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. [mre] [ask] [Help] PS Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean.

Comment: Clearly this can be expected to be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research. [tour]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality with the `exists` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   combinedoffers_tbl c
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   offers_tbl o
               WHERE  o.offer_id IN (c.offer_id, c.combinedwithoffer_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM combinedofferstbl c
INNER JOIN offers_tbl o ON o.offer_id = c.offer_id
                           OR o.offer_id = c.combinedwithoffer_id
```